# Dont Follow Inviter on SIgnUp if Admin User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, admin

I have created a BETA Invitation system by following this tutorial. http://railscasts.com/episodes/124-beta-invitations. Users can also follow one another in my Rails app.

**Currently, I have two methods:**

1. Allows the User to follow all ADMIN USERS on Sign up.
2. Allows the User to follow INVITER on sign up.

**The problem I am having is:**

```
no such column: TRUE: SELECT DISTINCT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN 
"invitations" ON "invitations"."id" = "users"."invitation_id" WHERE
(invitations.recipient_email = 'spedroza@usc.edu' OR users.admin IS TRUE)
```

Is there anyway to fix the second method so it wont follow the inviter if he is an ADMIN USER?

**MODEL**

USER

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :invitation_token

  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed

  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                               class_name:  "Relationship",
                               dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

  has_many :sent_invitations, :class_name => 'Invitations', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
  belongs_to :invitation

  after_create follow_inviter_and_admins      #--------HERE!!

  def follow_inviter_and_admins               #--------HERE!!
     return true if admin?
     users = User.joins(:invitation).where('invitations.recipient_email = ? OR users.admin IS admin', email).uniq
     users.each do |user|
       self.follow!(user)
     end
  end

  def invitation_token
    invitation.token if invitation
  end

  def invitation_token=(token)
    self.invitation = Invitation.find_by_token(token)
  end

  def following?(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id)
  end

  def follow!(other_user)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

end
```

RELATIONSHIPS

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :followed_id

  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"

  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

INVITATION

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :recipient_email, :sender_id, :sent_at, :token

  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User"

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  before_create :generate_token

  private

   def generate_token
      self.token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)
   end

end
```

**SCHEMA**

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "invitation_id"
    t.integer  "invitation_limit"
    t.boolean  "admin",                  :default => false   #----------HERE!!
    t.timestamp "created_at",                                :null => false
    t.timestamp "updated_at",                                :null => false
    t.string    "password_reset_token"
    t.timestamp "password_reset_sent_at"
  end

  create_table "invitations", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.string   "recipient_email"
    t.string   "token"
    t.datetime "sent_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can find all unique values in table users.

```
# user.rb

after_create :follow_inviter_and_admins

def follow_inviter_and_admins
  return true if admin?
  sender_id = Invitation.where(recipient_email: email).first.try(:sender_id)
  users = User.where('id = ? OR users.admin = ?', sender_id, true).uniq
  users.each do |user|
    self.follow!(user)
  end
end
```

something like this should select distinct values from table `users` which are admins or inviter. Because the values are unique the error should gone away

Comment: if I catch your idea correctly you would like to skip this callback for admins. So you can just add an option after callback `unless: :admin?` [details](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#using-if-and-unless-with-a-symbol). Of course user should respond to this method! Or you can add 'if condition' to the method `follow_inviter_and_admins`

Comment: you don't need two callbacks any more. You can use my example for one callback. And if you would like not to setup followings for admins just add in the first line in method `return true if admin?`

Comment: I change sql query in the answer, please check it. if error is still there please report what DB do you use?

Comment: i use ummm sqlite....ive edited the method to how i have it so far. i could finally sign in. BUT when the user signs in....He Follows Himself (not admin) and the Inviter. so its half way there lol

Comment: dude thanks so much for sticking it out with me and helping me out. I wish i can double rate you. Awesome it works finally!! :)

Answer (score 0):

ok try this

```
def follow_inviter                                
 inviter = Invitation.find_all_by_recipient_email(email)
 inviter.each do |invite|
 unless self.follow?invite.sender
  self.follow!(invite.sender)
 end
 end
end
```